# Returned Value of update operation

Tags: restful-architecture

What is the best method to returned value of update method
is True to return whole updated row if only one filed updated in this row 
Or only should return success message and during this message, should programmer re render interface with updated values

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking `REST`, the client will `PUT` a resource, while the server will update it, and then return a response containing feedback. This can be the `HTTP Status Code`, and either be the updated resource (if successful) so that the client can use it (without submitting a new `GET` request), or an error resource so that the client can know what went wrong (and possibly correct that).

Now if this update will translate into multiple table and even row updates, that's just your internal implementation, of which the client doesn't know about - all he knows is the contract, represented by the resource.